# Printer won't connect via DNS-SD, "unreachable"

Tags: ubuntu, networking, printer, brother

I am trying to install a networked printer (Brother HL-L2390DW). The Add Printer dialog finds it without issue, but no means of installing it allows it to work.

I've tried the Brother drivers, IPP driverless, and the `brlaser` alternative OSS driver.

Comment: If you don't show what you did, and what went wrong, then the best that we can tell you is "something went wrong, somewhere".

Answer (score 0):

I found [this Redhat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1614978) that seemed relevant. My `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file had the following contents:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

The fix in the linked thread is to add `mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]`, so I modified the line to be this:

```
hosts:          files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Installing the printer worked at this point.